# What kind of property a javabean can have?

Tags: java, properties, javabeans

What kind of properties can a javabean possess? 
As i have only four options, but i am not sure which are correct.

1. Indexed Properties
2. bound properties
3. constrained properties
4. limited properties

Comment: I have been using Java for 20 years and I can't say I'm familiar with this question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexed, bound, and constrained are the terms used in the [java beans documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html). Not sure what "limited" is.

Comment: Thanks @teppic this helped.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen This is the answer i was looking for. Please upwote my question at least. Thanks